# inkwell/llvm-sys not able to compile on windows

Tags: rust, llvm, llvm-ir

I am working with LLVM to build a small compiler in Rust using inkwell (inkwell uses llvm-sys, so it is relevant to it too).

First of all, compiled windows binaries on llvm's github **do not include needed tools for building on top of llvm.** Also after compiling llvm from sources, I was having an issues of not able to compile said crates, having different errors saying things like "Files/LLVM/Target.h not found!", etc.

First of all some solutions that worked for some people:

1. Cleaning the project (`cargo clean`)
2. Adding "<installation path>/LLVM/bin" to env Path.
3. If you are using inkwell, you still need to reference appropriate llvm-sys version in `Cargo.toml`:

   ```
   llvm-sys-160 = { package="llvm-sys", version = "160.1.4" } # For LLVM 16.x
   ```

Answer (score 1):

Turns out llvm-sys doesn't understand spaces in the path to LLVM (default installation path for LLVM is `C:\Program Files\LLVM\`).
So the whole solution will be install it into the directory with no spaces:

(Delete LLVM, if you already have one, -> install cmake and visual studio (I used 2022))

(Everything is done from VS Developer Console)

1. From Visual Studio Installer you need make sure you have `Visual C++ ATL v141-143` or `C++ ATL for latest v141-143`
2. git clone needed version of llvm using: `git clone https://github.com/llvm/llvm-project.git --branch release/16.x` (change the release version to one you need, it has to have format of `release/<major>.x`)
3. `cd llvm-project` -> `cd llvm` -> `mkdir build` -> `cd build`
4. `cmake .. "-DCMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX=C:\LLVM\"` (add more cmake flags if you want)
5. after the config is done (do not exit build directory): `cmake --build . --target install --config Release`
6. wait until the build is fully done, and then check if `C:\LLVM\bin` is in your PATH, if not add it.
   Done, this should allows the llvm-sys/inkwell to build.